# Android. Выполнение операций вставки и обновления строк таблицы из SQLite в UI-потоке. Всегда ли это плохо?

Tags: android, многопоточность, sqlite, android-asynctask

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня возник такой вопрос, ответа на который, я к сожалению, не нашел... Все Android-разработчики настоятельно рекомендуют выполнять абсолютно ВСЕ операции с БД в отдельном потоке (использовать **AsyncTask** или **AsyncTaskLoader**). С операцией получения данных тут все понятно, оно реально можно загрузить систему при огромном количестве строк, поэтому тут использование лоадеров вполне обоснованно. Но я сейчас пишу простое приложение (обычный чеклист), в котором возникли две простых задачи:

- При установке checkbox'a соответствующей задачи устанавливать в БД значение *IsDone=true|false* для строки (т.е простой запрос вида ***UPDATE Tasks SET IsDone=true WHERE TaskId=10***)
- Добавлять задачу в БД из отдельного активити и закрывать его. (Естественно, взаимодействие пользователя с активити здесь не нужно, пока строка "добавляется").

Так вот, вопрос заключается в следующем. Нужно ли на каждые такие простые запросы к БД лепить отдельно свои **AsynсTask'и**, мучаться с синхронизацией потоков, и тем самым превращать свой код в "вермишель" из **AsyncTask'ов**. Хотелось бы узнать мнение опытных разработчиков. Всегда ли вы помещаете запросы к БД в отдельные потоки, или все же такие простые запросы (какие привел я в пример) оставляете в UI-потоке?

Comment: если задача: менять только true|false, то можете использовать SharedPreferenses  без асинтасков и runOnUIThread

Comment: Да, все IO операции нужно делать в отдельных потоках. В компании где я работаю последний год мы это делаем с помощью [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), очень классная штука, правда тонкостей и подводных камней в ней не мало. Но если разобраться то на ней можно делать потрясающие вещи очень компактным кодом, особенно в связке с [Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda). А до того как подсесть на RxJava мы использовали [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice). Вот кстати [небольшой обзорчик](https://habrahabr.ru/post/252629/) на тему.